# iframe doubleclick event not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a way too primitive question, but it really drives me nuts, because I cannot make it work. So, I have an `iframe` on a page and I want to have doubleclick event. The browser I test it is FireFox. This is what I've tried:

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByClassName("cke_wysiwyg_frame")[0];
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
iframeDocument.ondblclick = function () {
    alert("Test 1");
}
```

and this:

```
iframeDocument.addEventListener("dblclick", function () {
    alert("Test 2");
});
```

For some strange reason it only works, when I open console for debugging. When the console is closed, then it stops working.

In other browsers which I tried - Chrome and IE - it does not work at all. In IE for example I tried:

```
 iframeDocument.attachEvent("dblclick", function () {
     alert("Test 3");
 });
```

But it does not work. So, what is wrong with that? Why in FF it works with the console opened, and stops working when it is closed? And how to make it work in other browsers? Shame on me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observe the load event of the iframe. Once it fired you can assign the ondblclick event to the document inside the iframe.

```
iframeDocument.attachEvent("onload", function () {
    this.contentWindow.document.ondblclick = function() { alert('it work\'s'); }
});
```

Comment: I fixed it a little bit to support other browsers and it works, Thank you for pointing in the right direction!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I never tested this for browsers other than IE. Can you post the last version, it think it may be helpful for somebody.